# jquery autocomplete for integers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am currently using jquery auto complete .The funcionality is working fine with charecters meaning

when i type "H" it is pulling "HDHR " meaning all he codes begining with "H". But i have an intger column which has number 01919, 10191 ,89191, etc . Here when i type 0 it is still pulling all the numbers even starting with 1 and 8 . Below is my code .

**Code Behind**

```
public string SuggestionList = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

    }

    string sql = "select mnr_workorder  from workorder_vw where mnr_status='A' ";
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConStr);
    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        OracleDataReader dr;

        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SuggestionList))
            {
                SuggestionList += "\"" + dr["MNR_WORKORDER"].ToString() + "\"";
            }
            else
            {
                SuggestionList += ", \"" + dr["MNR_WORKORDER"].ToString() + "\"";
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
}
```

**ASPX PAGE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="TextBox1">
        WorkOrder no:
    </label>
    <input id="TextBox1" />
</div>
$(function() { 
    var availableTags = [<%= SuggestionList %>]; 
    $( "#TextBox1" ).autocomplete(
        { source: availableTags });
```

i am wondering how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jqueryUI autocomplete widget does not find items *starting* with what you have typed. It finds items *containing* what you've typed. So in your case, if you start typing `0`, it finds any item in the source which contains the character `0`.

If you check my [basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/BT4TP/) which contains the following 3 items:

```
var list = ['0123456465','0987654321','123456']
```

And you type a `5` into the box you'll see all 3 choices come up. None start with a 5, but all have a 5 within them.

Lucky for you, the documentation contains an example which does exactly what you want: [Using a custom source callback to match only the beginning of terms](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1)

Applied to your case that would look something like:

```
var availableTags = [<%= SuggestionList %>]; 
$( "#TextBox1" ).autocomplete(
    { 
         source: function( request, response ) {
                 var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                 response( $.grep( availableTags , function( item ){
                       return matcher.test( item );
                 }));
        }
    });
```

Live example having updated my example above: http://jsfiddle.net/BT4TP/1/ - now when you type `0` only 2 entries are shown, and when you type `5` nothing is shown.

(BTW: you're also including jquery UI twice in your html, that's of course unnecessary)